# Spring Component dependency injection of a field with multiple implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a class MyMessageConsumer which is a spring Component. I have autowired MessageReceiver interface as below :

```
    @Component
    @Scope("prototype")
    public class MyMessageConsumer {

     @Autowired
     private MessageReceiver messageReceiver;

    }
```

I want to create multiple bean instances of MyMessageConsumer each with different implementations of MessageReceiver say TextMessageReceiver, XMLMessageReceiver, JSONMessageReceiver.

```
    // If a setter is provided in MyMessageConsumer, then it would be suffiecent. But how to do it without setter.
```

Is it possible to inject different implementation without a setter method in the above scenario? Otherwise please suggest the best alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use _constructor-based_ dependency injection.Both approaches of Injecting dependency on Spring bean has there pros and cons.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Mihir. In "MyMessageConsumer" I am not supposed to make any changes.
I want to use @Bean(name="MyMessageConsumer_1") , @Bean(name="MyMessageConsumer_2") and write the methods which return that instance by injecting different implementations of MessageReceiver to each of the instance.
Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 1):

One option is removing the @autowired in the MyMessageConsumer.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyMessageConsumer {

    private MessageReceiver messageReceiver;

    public MessageReceiver getMessageReceiver() {
        return messageReceiver;
    }

    public void setMessageReceiver(MessageReceiver messageReceiver) {
        this.messageReceiver = messageReceiver;
    }
}
```

Then define you MessageReceiver beans

```
@Bean
public TextMessageReceiver textMessageReceiver() {
    return new TextMessageReceiver();
}

@Bean
public XMLMessageReceiver xMLMessageReceiver() {
    return new XMLMessageReceiver();
}
```

Then you need to define your MessageConsumers

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public MyMessageConsumer myMessageConsumer1(TextMessageReceiver textMessageReceiver) {
    MyMessageConsumer m = new MyMessageConsumer();
    m.setMessageReceiver(textMessageReceiver);
    return m;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public MyMessageConsumer myMessageConsumer2(XMLMessageReceiver xMLMessageReceiver) {
    MyMessageConsumer m = new MyMessageConsumer();
    m.setMessageReceiver(xMLMessageReceiver);
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Hi @reos, it would work without Autowire and by using the setter method. But think of this way, the class is not written by us and is provided from an external module which we are dependent on, in such case we would not be able to modify the code. So, how do we inject instance-specific dependencies without setter methods ?

Comment: Thanks reos for your response and suggestion.

Comment: I think you can use reflection to change the value of the messageReceiver field, http://www.sevagas.com/?Modify-any-Java-class-field-using